# Spoilers are showing in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, spoilers

I've noticed that when reading posts with `>!` spoiler blocks in them, they get displayed as normal blockquotes.

That could be annoying at best, screen breaking at worst.

Comment: [Obligatory](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9M0VG.jpg).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is implemented in the next version of the app, 1.0.29.

And just to make things a bit meta (pun extremely intended):

[image]

Comment: Hallelujah! Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Example:

> This should not be visible, but it is.

[image: Android spoilers]

Comment: It's tempting to create another screenshot and update your post for added recursive fun! :)

Comment: It's tempting to propose an edit with [the image in my comment above](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9M0VG.jpg) in the spoiler block :-)