# Tags in spoilers are always visible

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, spoilers

Tags in spoilers are always visible, even if you don't put your mouse on the spoiler (on [this Code Golf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26316/9275) for example). See the screenshot:

[image: Spoiler bug]

---

Looks a bit strange on this site too:

> [this-is-a](/questions/tagged/this-is-a) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) that needs [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!

Comment: Another side-effect of their annoying use of the color attribute to hide the spoiler. I don't see why they wouldn't just use opacity...

Comment: @animuson: In that case, “text” would be visible in `>! <pre></pre> text` (not that it’s common). Setting `color` for the element, then restoring `color` for its children and setting `opacity` could work.

Comment: @Charmander I'd care a lot less about that scenario since it's not valid.

Comment: This is yet another bug that would be fixed by implementing [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217779/the-css-for-spoilers-is-a-mess-lets-fix-it).

Comment: This also happens on main sites, just tested and it happens on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @animuson funny, you're now part of "they". :)

Comment: Anyway, good news is that this bug does not affect mobile web and apps. :)

Comment: I just noticed this today. It still happens here on Meta.SA.

Comment: @Pro the answer you used as example is deleted, can you find a different answer having this bug?

Comment: @ShadowWizard When I come across one, I'll put it here. In the meantime, the 'live' example should be enough.

Comment: @Pat I was about to  remove any mention of "beta sites" as well when starting the bounty, but found that the bug is different between the themes.  On beta sites, the whole tag is visible, as we can see in the screenshot, while on graduated sites (like here) only its placeholder is seen. Both bugs of course, but still... the original report is about the beta sites.

Comment: @Sha The exact same behavior happens on SO, complete tags there, so it is much broader than just beta sites. (Or, sorry, that was the image of course). Feel free to roll back.

Comment: This has been fixed btw, needs a status-completed methinks..

Answer (score 6):

That is a bug indeed, but with a simple fix.

This CSS overrides the styling on tags when inside a spoiler:

```
.spoiler .required-tag {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.spoiler .post-tag {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.spoiler .moderator-tag {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

This can be simplified if there was a single `.tag` class.