# Multiple spoilers don't work too well on Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, spoilers

App version: 1.0.31
Device: Nexus 7
Problem: When looking at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230533/254778) question, I visited the [other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26316) that was linked, and noticed that spoiler tags didn't work too well when there was more than one spoiler in a question. When I clicked on the 'Spoiler: tap to view' option, the last spoiler was shown. It didn't matter which one I clicked on, it was always the last one that was shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 1.0.32 this is handled better, thanks!