# <kbd> elements are not hidden in a spoilers block

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, markdown, spoilers

Recently noticed the following:

> The catchphrase <kbd>"Danger, Will Robinson!"</kbd> originates with the series, but was only ever used once in it.

Is it intentional to have `<kbd>` text visible inside spoilers markdown?

---

**Image for future reference:**
[image: kbd showing in spoilers]

Comment: Do we want peoples keyboards disappearing on them though?

Comment: This was posted in Arqade Meta earlier today _(because how often do we use spoilers outside of gaming?)_ Maybe the other question should be migrated to the main meta site (https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12541/kbd-elements-are-not-hidden-in-a-spoilers-block)

Comment: Not sure if it is fixed in [SOUP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217779/the-css-for-spoilers-is-a-mess-lets-fix-it/217780#217780).

Comment: Apparently, it works in the app, but not the browser.

Comment: Is there an example of this being an issue on any specific question? (Not discounting the issue, it should still be fixed)

Comment: It might even be desirable: teasers inside of hints!

Comment: Looks like the same issue as with [tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230533/295232). Also, spoilers are heavily used in Puzzling, Movies, SciFi, ...

Comment: @Glorfindel Looks like issue with tags was fixed earlier this year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in the next build via my answer at [Tags in spoilers on Meta Stack Overflow are always visible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355161/tags-in-spoilers-on-meta-stack-overflow-are-always-visible/356538#356538).