# Lag for displaying text within `` in spoiler tags

Tags: bug, markdown

In [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32160/20197), the user used text in backticks (`) within a spoiler tag. When hovering over the spoiler tag, all the text within the backticks appears instantly, and the rest of the text fades in like normal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This happens to all questions on non-SO sites where you include code in such spoiler.

Comment: Yeah, that's on my list to fix. It's fixed on some sites, but not on the beta site stylesheet.

Comment: Okay, that's cool :). Thanks for the reply.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217779/the-css-for-spoilers-is-a-mess-lets-fix-it; the client-side fix in [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) described there fixes this bug too.