# Spoilers on Area 51 Discussions slightly visible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, area-51, spoilers

Spoiler formatting was used on the question "[On 'Sex and Intimacy' should spoiler tags be used to hide sketches/diagrams/images?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19068/95902)"

and it isn't completely hidden.

[image: Random Picture of spoiler formatting]

it looks like the text is colored assuming a grey background.

I can see how this could be an issue if it is used on other sites and the spoiler isn't exactly functioning the way it should be.

Comment: Agree it is a bug, but quite minor as the text is very hard to read until you hover it. Dunno what happens with pictures though, might be worth testing maybe?

Comment: FWIW, it seems that the [generic spoiler styling fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217779/the-css-for-spoilers-is-a-mess-lets-fix-it) included in [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) fixes this issue too. I was about to comment that this bug seems to be fixed, before realizing that I had SOUP enabled. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that Area 51 Discussions uses the new responsive design that is now used globally across the rest of the Stack Exchange network, this issue is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).