# Bullet points prefer to remain hidden

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, spoilers

In spoiler tags bullet points will only change their visible state when the browser is scrolled up or down, with the arrow keys or the mouse scroll.

The bullet points will change their visible state to however visible the rest of the spoiler is at the time of scrolling. For instance, if you hover your cursor on the spoiler tag, the text will become visible but the bullet points will not, if at this point you scroll down one tick; suddenly the bullet points will become just as visible as the text in the spoiler. If you move your mouse so that the spoiler is not shown and then scroll the screen, the bullet points will disappear. If the text in the spoiler is part way between fully visible and fully hidden and the screen is scrolled, the bullet points will become partially visible and remain that way until the screen is scrolled again.

[The post that I noticed it on](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7133/106901)

[image: bullet points weird]

Note this is on chrome on windows 8.

Comment: Uh, not for me, you might want to add stuff like browser version and such.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Does happen for me, both on Gaming.SE and here on Meta.SE, on Chrome 46, if I turn off [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Answer (score 3):

This is a Chrome (actually webkit) bug. For some reason, the CSS color transition set on spoilers doesn't work on the list bullets - they don't get repainted as expected.

There are no specific style rules to list items.

This works as expect in Internet Explorer and FireFox.

Declining, as this is not something we can fix - webkit needs to be fixed.

Comment: Well, you *could*, if you applied [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217780). ;-)

Comment: This seems to be fixed now, anyway. YAY! :D