# Hidden "rollover" blockquoted text is impossible to see when using Chrome (iOS)

Tags: bug, markdown, google-chrome, iphone, spoilers

There is no "rollover" capability with Chrome (iOS anyway), so rollover/hidden blockquoted text (marked by `>!`) is impossible to view when using a browser in "full site" mode:

Eg

> Normal blockquoted text is fine

but the following is inaccessible when using Chrome (on iPhone)

> This is not possible to see on iPhone

The field is not clickable or highlightable (to attempt copy-paste).

Comment: On an android you can show the spoiler text by clicking on it

Comment: are you talking about the IOS-app or just via browser on the iPhone?

Comment: @bluefeet browser. The app is completely useless (TBH I have long forgotten it exists)

Comment: @RichardTingle you can't click on it. You can't even highlight it to try copy paste to see it.

Comment: Is this supposed to have the android tag on it?

Comment: No, it shouldn't have an android app tag on it. This isn't an iOS app report either. Android app users: does someone want to open a bug report on the Android app's version of the problem?

Comment: Earlier there was an android tag added to it, and an android only answer posted. Seems both are gone now.

Comment: @Bohemian it's strange, I tested this in both Safari and Chrome on my iPhone and it says _Click to show spoiler_. Once I do that, I see the text just fine.

Comment: @Jonathan Android app just displays the spoiler text always

Comment: @RichardTingle Yeah, so we should probably have a bug report about it :)

Comment: @Jonathan [the people from the past got there first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196164/spoilers-are-showing-in-the-android-app)

Comment: Nope, spoilers work just fine for me. iPhone and Chrome here, can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @bluefeet I can see no such button/link/action "click to show". I'm using iPhone 5, but I am still using iOS 6 though (7 hasn't been out *that* long, and for various reasons I don't want to upgrade) and the latest version of Chrome

Comment: How do you even click something on an iPhone?

Comment: Re the duplicate target, is this about the mobile version or full version of the site?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn you can't click on arbitrary places, only buttons, links, etc. You can (with great difficulty) highlight and copy text on a web page by using the press-and-hold gesture on the text, but even this does nothing on the hidden text

Comment: It's because Android is better </religious-war>

Comment: @bluefeet "Click to show spoiler" works in the mobile view, but not in the desktop view. Bohemian, I'm not sure what our plans are for supporting desktop views on mobile browsers, but I suspect they're along the lines of "use the mobile view, Luke".

Answer (score 0):

Erm... OK. I'm gonna have to disagree.

Here's your question in Safari on an iPhone 5s.

You'll never guess what the **"Click to show spoiler"** button does.

---

[image: This page on iPhone]

Comment: I use iPhone 5, but Safari works (yes, I should have checked), Chrome doesn't. Chrome is the culprit - I'll change the Q to emphasise Chrome.